# How to prove if sets A and B satisfy $|A\cup B|=|\mathbb R|$, then $|A|=|\mathbb R|$ or $|B|=|\mathbb R|$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, cardinals

I saw this problem when I'm learning set theory and real analysis.

This problem can easily be solved if we acknowledge **The continuum hypothesis(CH)**, because if the cardinality of A or B is not bigger than $\aleph_0$, then the cardinality of the union of A and B is not bigger than $\aleph_0$.

But this problem doesn't seem to rely on the CH. Without the CH, I don't know how to deal with this kind of set whose cardinality is between $\aleph_0$ and $\aleph_1$.

Help and thanks!

(We discuss this problem in ZFC set theory.)

Comment: Obviously at least one of $A$ or $B$ must be infinite, as otherwise $A \cup B$ is finite. This brings us to a hint: Can you show that $|A \cup B| = \max (|A|, |B|)$ when $|A|$ or $|B|$ is infinite? Do you see how to use this to solve your problem?

Comment: Some choice is absolutely needed, since it's consistent with ZF that the statement is false.

Comment: @HallaSurvivor , assuming A has bigger cardinality, we just need to prove $|A\cup B|\le|A|$ and $|A\cup B|\ge |A|$. The second one is obvious. However, I don't think the first one is easy to prove without the CH.

Comment: @AsafKaragila , thanks for your correction, we discuss this problem in ZFC set theory.

Comment: Victor, what @HallaSurvivor said is a general statement. Since $|A|+|A|=|A|$ for every infinite set, $|A\cup B|\leq|A|+|B|\leq|A|+|A|=|A|$.

Comment: @AsafKaragila , I see. But how to prove "$|A|+|A|=|A|$ for every infinite set"? Do we need to use the axiom of choice?

Comment: Yes, that is where the axiom of choice comes into the picture.